# Zoom level issue with openlayers 5 and custom tile generation using gdal2tiles

Tags: gdal, arcgis-10.2, openlayers, openstreetmap, gdal2tiles

Now i have changed my code but the output is still not what is expected, because the resolution provided is of 0 - 8 zoom but my minZoom starts from 12 itself,
will i get my tiles rendered ?? how exactly openlayers will understand that at a zoom of 12 it needs to fetch 0(zoom) resolution tile image or at zoom 13 it needs to fetch 1(zoom) resolution???

```
var resolutions = [156367.7919628329, 78183.89598141646, 39091.94799070823, 19545.973995354114, 9772.986997677057,
 4886.4934988385285,2443.2467494192642,1221.6233747096321,610.8116873548161];

 var extent  = [454019.0871110868, 36291.71352911883, 454248.1414938449, 
  36399.381018930886];

 const map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
      controls: [],
      view: new ol.View({
         projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:21096'),
         center: ol.proj.transform([32.6000, 0.3290], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:21096'),
         resolutions: resolutions,
         zoom: 12
    })
});


const tileGrid = new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
     extent : extent,
     resolutions : resolutions})

   var xyzLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: "http://localhost:8089/gis-web/map/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            tileGrid: tileGrid
    })
});

map.addLayer(xyzLayer);


 const setOlNonHierarchical = (layer) => {
 var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
   loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
    showLoader(loader);
    let startIndex, maxFeatures, workspace;
    workspace = $('#prop_workspace').val();
    maxFeatures = $('#prop_max').val();
    startIndex = $('#prop_start_index').val();
    var proj = projection.getCode();
      var url = `${common_layers_url}${workspace}/${layer.geom}/${layer.title}/${maxFeatures}/${startIndex}`;
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      var onError = function() {
        vectorSource.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
      }
      xhr.onerror = onError;
      xhr.onload = function() {

        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          fadeLoader(loader);
          vectorSource.addFeatures(
              vectorSource.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText));
               //Set House No for Building
               if(layer.title=='Buildings'){
                      if(!isHouseNoSet)
                      setTimeout(setHouseNo,100);
               }
               //Open Draw Event for New Building Survey 
               if(layer.title==$("#newBuildingSurveyId").attr('layer-text') && openSurveyNew==1){
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    selectedOpenEditFeatures();
                },100);
               }
        } else {
          onError();
        }
      }
      xhr.send();
    }
  });


 map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Vector({
       zIndex: layer.layerZindex,
       name_: layer.title,
       shortcode_:layer.layerShortCode,
       geomType: layer.geom,
       renderMode: 'image',
       customStyle: false,
       source:vectorSource
    }));

}
```

Okk so this the code from where my vector sources are getting added which show up at zoom 12

Comment: When you ask for a help with the code, existing code should always be included in the question. Please, edit the question and include relevant part of your code in the body of the question.

Comment: @TomazicM I have edited the question with other code and image , can u please help me with this issue ??

Comment: I don't see any declaration of min zoom in your code.

Comment: Even if i specify minZoom which is 12 , i will not get the tiles right?? because the tiles that are generated are from zoom 0 - 8 only, there are no tiles after 8 zoom , so basically what i want is zoom manupilation for example if my minZoom is 12 the tiles of 0 zoom should be loaded , if my zoom is 13 the tiles of 1 zoom should be loaded

Comment: As I wrote: please, include **all code relevant to your problem** in the question.

Comment: Now i have also added the minZoom option but still it gets the same error, because openlayers checks the current zoom and tries to load the matching tile with that zoom, that is all the relevant code that i have

Comment: As I wrote: please, include **all code relevant to your problem** in the question. There is no code for other layer, no code for view ...

Comment: @TomazicM , sorry for that , so now i have added my ol.Map code with the view and my base OSM layer added

Comment: @TomazicM can u please put some light on this issue

Comment: I'm at my job now. I don't think my government is willing to pay for pro bono advice service.

Comment: apologies, whenever ur free

Answer (score 1):

If you have tile layer with different tile schema than base layer, you have to define tile grid `ol.tilegrid.TileGrid` for that layer, where you specify layer extent with `extent` option and and zoom resolutions (tile resolution for each zoom) with `resolutions` option.

You have to specify these resolutions also in view definition, so they become you native map resolutions and also limit min and max zoom.

Below is an example from my map I'm actually using for testing purposes (tile schema is a bit specific, but that's not relevant for this case).

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:3912',
           '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=682,-203,480,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');                   
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

var layerResol = [658, 500, 130, 125, 42, 41, 21,  12,  4, 2, 1];          
var layerExtent = [374371.84, 30513.32, 624119.18, 195517.48];

var tileGrid = new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
      extent: layerExtent,
      resolutions: layerResol
    });

var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://prostor4.gov.si:80/ows2-m-pub/wms',
    attributions: '&copy <a href="http://www.gu.gov.si/">GURS</a>',
    params: {
      'LAYERS': '',
      'FORMAT': 'image/png',
      'VERSION': '1.3.0'
    },
    tileGrid: tileGrid,
    projection: 'EPSG:3912'
  })
});

var urlFunc = layer.getSource().getTileUrlFunction().bind(layer.getSource());
layer.getSource().setTileUrlFunction(function (tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
    var products = [ "DPK1000", "DPK750", "DPK750", "DPK750", "DPK500", "DPK250", 'DPK250', 'DTK50', 'DTK50', "DTK25", "DTK25", "SVR", "SV" ];
    var z = tileCoord[0];
    this.updateParams({ 'LAYERS':'SI.GURS.DK:' + products[z]});
    return urlFunc(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection);
});

var view = new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:3912',
    center: ol.extent.getCenter(layerExtent),
    resolutions: layerResol,
    zoom: 2
  });

var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [osmLayer, layer]
});

map.setView(view);
```

Comment: But I'm not using any WMS service, I have created tiles using gdal library which is locally present, is there any way that i can manipulate my zoom , such that if my zoom is 12 , 0th zoom tile is fetched , if zoom is 13, 1st zoom tile is fetched and so on , using ol.source.XYZ

Comment: Tile source is not important in this case, only layer extent and layer resolutions. For your tile layer you have to specify layer extent with `extent` option and layer resolutions for each of your nine zooms with `resolutions` options.

Comment: I have edited my code and posted but no results , if u can review it please

Comment: Option `zoom: 12` is not OK. On the basis of resolutions, your zooms now go from 0 to 8.

Comment: Set zoom option to `zoom: 2` and see what happens.

Comment: yes that is the problem, my website zoom starts from 12 - 20 max, only the tiles that i have generated are from 0-8 , due to which im not able to fetch the tiles because my zoom for my website starts from 12 but the tile generated by gdal2tiles.py is from 0-8 because the geoTiff image is a droneImagery, so if create tiles of this geoTiff using gdal2tiles.py script and go beyound 8 zoom the tiles images that are generated are not clear, so the tiles calling sequence should be like from 12-20 zoom(from website) but tiles fetched should be from 0-8

Comment: Did you try to set view zoom option to `zoom: 2`?

Comment: yes , tried,  i got the tiles as well, but what openlayers does is it takes the current zoom  which is the z in my url option for the source and then calculates x and y coordinates of the tiles as per the zoom , and as I said my website landing page zoom is 12 so when I zoom in to 12 the actual view of my website is lost because i have other vector layers which are used only starting from zoom 12 , I cant keep my website on 2 zoom , it has to start from 12 and the tiles should be fetched from 12 zoom , I thought there should be some logic that i can add to tileUrlFunction or tileLoadFunction

Comment: There are ne other layers specified in the code in your question. This is the third time I'm repeating this:  please, include **all code relevant to your problem** in the question.

Comment: I have added  all the code now , sorry i'm new to this so...

Comment: Only now I looked at your extension and resolutions number. Extension covers an area approx. 230 x 105 map meters. At zoom 0 this is one 256 x 256 tile that covers whole extent. This is resolution around 1, but you have 156367 in your specs. This is standard resolution that covers the whole world in one tile and is so completely wrong.

Comment: So what do I need to do now ???

Comment: You have to specify correct resolutions. If you don't know how to do that, ask a separate question about how to display custom made tiles, with all the details about tiles: crs, extent, number of zooms, example of tile at zoom 0, example of tile at highest zoom etc.